# How to place labels on GraphicsRow?

Tags: graphics, image, visualization

I have a list of image and a list of labels and I am trying to combine them using `GraphicsRow`. I didn't see any "label" related option in GraphicsRow so wondering how should I combine it.

```
labelsPlot = {"(a) Ground Truth", "(b) FCN", "(c) Mask RCNN", 
  "(d) SETR", "(e) SepDet"}

MapThread[
 Placed[#1, #2] &, {{gtPlot, fcnPlot, mrcnnPlot, setrPlot, 
   sepDetPlot}, labelsPlot}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try with ``Labeled`` instead of ``Placed`` and then ``Row`` instead of ``GraphicsRow``.

Answer (score 3):

Not clear on what you want as your final output, but the following may give you some ways to approach the problem.

[image]

```
Grid[{
  labelsPlot,
  images
  }]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{
  images,
  labelsPlot
  }]
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
Grid[Transpose[{
   images,
   labelsPlot
   }],
 Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]